# Docker | Unable to Access jarfile?

Tags: java, docker

i want to build a minecraft spigot minecraft server with docker.

So i get in touch with docker and i dont think i get the entire hang of it.

When i run the image as a cotainer i get:

```
Recreating minecraft-spigot-1165x86_64_mc_1 ... done
Attaching to minecraft-spigot-1165x86_64_mc_1
mc_1  | Error: Unable to access jarfile spigot.jar
minecraft-spigot-1165x86_64_mc_1 exited with code 1
```

I dont know why it cant start the jar file. I already tried using "Entrypoint" and "CMD". Both dosent work :/. I added "RUN ls" so i can see if its copied, and yes its showing the file when i build the image. pls help :)

Used Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL maintainer="CruZer606@private"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt install default-jdk -y

RUN mkdir /srv/minecraft && cd /srv/minecraft

COPY spigot.jar /srv/minecraft/spigot.jar

WORKDIR /srv/minecraft

RUN ls -al

RUN echo "eula = true" > /srv/minecraft/eula.txt

EXPOSE 25565

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xms4096M", "-Xmx4096M", "-jar", "spigot.jar"]
```

Comment: Can you verify that the container is not suspended (`docker ps -a` should not list it, if so, get its container-id and call `docker rm <container-id>`), then rebuild & start the container?

Comment: I now deleted all useless docker containers and it did run. but when i now want to mount a port and or the filesystem as a volume i get this error: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "-v": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: How are you actually starting the container?  If you're trying to mount a volume on `/srv/minecraft` that will hide the jar file the image built; store your data somewhere else.